# How do you load-test your ASP.NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, performance, load-testing

I'm not sure where to start when it comes to load-testing ASP.NET applications. My team doesn't use VSTS so that option is out. Does anyone have any good suggestions or experience they can share?

Answer (score 2):

I'ved used Microsoft's free Web Application Stress Tool.  It lets you record a browsing session, then replay it using multiple clients.

[It seems that](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161284.aspx) Microsoft has pulled this application from the download center, but you can use [this alternative download](http://www.maurodalfreddo.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/web_stress_tool_setup.zip) (it may require 7-Zip to unpack).

Comment: I have used this too.  It was a bit fiddly to get set up, but once you worked out the details it was reasonably effective.  The biggest issue I had with other apps that I tried (eg. Pylot) was they didn't deal with viewstate very well.

Comment: I've tried a couple of performance testing apps, such as ANTS by Red Gate and dotTrace by JetBrains, but they weren't really what I was looking for (good for profiling bottlenecks, not really for load testing a server). I went to try this out but it appears the link is broken. I did a cursory Google search but those turned up broken links as well. :(

Comment: Try this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313559 or this http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6

Answer (score 1):

Red Gate Software has a product called ANTS that can be used to do this.
[Click Here for product link](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/dotnet_tools_overview.htm)

Comment: I tried this out and it seems to be a great product for locating bottlenecks in code. However, I'm more interested in something for simulating the stress of many users and test the load that creates on the application and server.

Answer (score 0):

Using [BrowserMob.com](http://browsermob.com/load-testing) is quite cheap for what it provides.  You can listen to an interview with the founder of Browser Mob [on Startup Success Podcast #18](http://startuppodcast.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/show-18-patrick-lightbody-browsermobcom/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Grinder**](http://grinder.sourceforge.net).

Its a nice Java Based Opensource tool, to load test webapps. Pretty lean as well.